# Giga Selfie Tech Explanation

Tags: photo-editing, digital

Can anyone help decipher the tech behind the Australia Tourism's Giga Selfie campaign? To know more about the campaign, click here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4LQnKdIBA0

Comment: Please include a short description in your question. Links break.

Comment: For anyone who wants to do some legwork the maker's site is  http://tapemyday.com/products/gigaselfie/ and another description is at http://www.gigaselfie.com.au/  It does mention it's powered by Canon, which makes me think it's a handful of DSLR's setup to take multiple images and stitching them at the back-end.  Though TMD seem to offer some interesting things like tracking 100's of people at once in video.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely to be an arrange of cameras using telephoto lenses. There is currently no "gigapixel" sensor, including big telescopes.

If they are that far it is easy to stich them seamlesly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they created a standard gigapixel image using a long lens and stiching and when you take a selfie, the camera takes a picture of only you and then merges the two.

To verify that, we would need more sample pictures: if I'm right, the surroundings should always be the same.

Comment: i doubt this could work correctly - the lighting and weather is constantly changing